# SignalR: Establishing a tunnel via proxy server failed

Tags: c#, asp.net, google-chrome, signalr

I have implemented signalR in Asp.Net webform it's working fine but when i hosted on my server its not working and in console of chrome browser showing below error.

> WebSocket connection to 'ws://demo.in/signalr/connect?transport=webSockets&clientProtocol=1.5&connectionToken=aoHc%2BkUmnhPuXWtRjo5iJyAOTzyM5xi6tY1nkUw5Y1AfTr2AWadAb4o4tfsWX1NpwCMFDsKvlKra49NLbeNoCIGCrzvAQ62aAIeYoWl9mixu%2BAOZXdHqbQzHOsVxBZPY&connectionData=%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22dashboardnewhub%22%7D%5D&tid=5' failed: Establishing a tunnel via proxy server failed.

1. My Asp.net Application framework version is 4.5.1
2. IIS version is 8.5
3. Windows Server is 2012R2
4. Wedsocket is enable

If anyone know please help me. Thank you in Advance

Comment: Even i am looking for this question answer

Comment: I have this issue too, but with one specific customer. They use TMG 2010 as a firewall gateaway

Answer (score 2):

if you are using proxy setting go to your system proxy setting Internet Options > Connection Tab >Lan settings > Advanced  Add your application Url or Ip "ws://demo.in" in exceptions addresses. otherwise you have to set it in your company proxy setting